# How to generate the top and perspective view of an object using ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js

I want to generate the top and perspective view of an object.

- **Input**: A 3d object, maybe .obj or .dae file.
- **Output**: the image files presenting the top and front view of the loaded object.

Here is some expected output:

[The perspective view of a chair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM2qJ.jpg)

[The top view of a chair:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCSXC.jpg)

Can anyone give me some suggestions to solve this problem? Demo may be preferred

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small three.js scene with your obj or collada-file loaded using the appropriate loaders. (see examples of the specific loaders). Then create the necessary cameras you want to have in the scene. See examples for orthographic and perspective cameras that come with three.js, too. 
To produce the images you want, you could use the toDataURL function, see this thread here and use google
[Three.js and HTML5 Canvas toDataURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811792/three-js-and-html5-canvas-todataurl)

in essence, after the objects are loaded, you could do something like:

```
  renderer.render(scene, topViewCamera);
  dataurl = canvas.toDataURL();
  renderer.render(scene, perspectiveCamera); 
  dataurl2 = canvas.toDataURL();
```

I think you could also use 2 renderTargets and then use those for output, too, but maybe if you are new to three.js, start with the toDataURL() method from HTML5.